# Create dojo.store.memory using XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, dojo.gridx, dojo

My data is originally stored in an xml file structured like this (with a bunch of entities,  rows in each entity and cells in each rows)

```
    <entity i=1>
        <row i =1>
           <cell i=1>
           <cell i=2>
        </row>

        <row i=2>
           <cell i=1>
           <cell i=2>
        </row>
    </entity>
```

Example I read from the dojo tutorial is this:

```
    require([

    'dojo/store/Memory',
    'gridx/Grid',
    'gridx/core/model/cache/Sync'
    ], function(Store, Grid, Cache){
  var store = new Store({
    data: [
        {id: 1, title: 'Hey There', artist: 'Bette Midler'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Love or Confusion', artist: 'Jimi Hendrix'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Sugar Street', artist: 'Andy Narell'}
    ]
});
......
});
```

How should I create the dojo store using XML stylesheet? Should I use embedded javascript in my XML stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use the `dojo/query` module to iterate through your XML document. The only thing you have to do first is to parse your XML (if it isn't already), for example:

```
require([ "dojo/query", "dojox/xml/parser", "dojo/dom-attr" ], function(query, xml, domAttr) {
    var content = xml.parse("<entity><row i=\"1\"><cell i=\"1\">Cell 1</cell><cell i=\"2\">Cell 2</cell></row><row i=\"2\"><cell i=\"1\">Cell 3</cell><cell i=\"2\">Cell 4</cell></row></entity>");
    var out = query("row", content).map(function(node) {
        var data = {};
        query("cell", node).forEach(function(cell) {
            data[domAttr.get(cell, "i")] = cell.textContent;
        });
        return data;
    });
    console.log(out);
});
```

This will result in an array of two objects where the value of the `i`  attribute is the property name and the text content of the `<cell>` element is the value.

```
[{
  "1": "Cell 1",
  "2": "Cell 2"
}, {
  "1": "Cell 3",
  "2": "Cell 4"
}]
```

Which you can then use in a store.

Full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUjN7/